# How to get list of get granted scopes with LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

How do I get the list of granted scopes? Similar to me/permissions on Facebook, or oauth2/v1/tokeninfo on Google Plus.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I came up with was changing the redirect uri dynamically based on the permissions I was requesting for the user, and extracting them as params. Eg,

`http://myapp/auth/linkedin/:scopes`

`:scopes` would be a string of the permissions joined by a `+` or whatever you want

Make sure to add these urls in your linkedin dev console, or it will get rejected. There aren't enough scopes for this to be a huge problem.

Not the cleanest solution, but it works as far as I can tell

Comment: Well okay, but this only tells you what scopes were added by the user at that point of time. The user is able to remove some scopes, and there should be a way to query the scopes that are "currently" available. (E.g. after the user has removed some of them.)

Comment: @nagylzs yeah, I totally get it; this is not an ideal solution. Well, ideally LinkedIn would just send the data like Facebook etc does. If there's a cleaner fix I'd love to know

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is still actual, but they do provide the list of all currently available scopes here on the app's page:

https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer

P.S. Please note, some of the fields (e.g. recommendations) are available only for approved apps.